# How do I find strings that contain two strings and replace one of them

Tags: regex

I have a lot of html files that one tag is using a wrong class and I need to replace them. I can find all the tags I need to have replaced, but I'm not sure how to correctly replace them.

I have something like this:

```
<div id="myDiv" att1="blah" class="classToBeReplaced"> blah </div>
```

So with `^(?=.*myDiv)(?=.*classToBeReplaced).*$`

I can find everything. And I want to replace to:

```
<div id="myDiv" att1="blah" class="newClass"> blah </div>
```

Some of those tags have different attributes, depending on the file they are located.
What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: Provide several different matches so that a proper regex can be created.

Comment: One better doesn't use regexes for processing these kind of tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I actually ended up using, after the help from @Bohemian, was this:

```
 (myDiv.*?)classToBeReplaced(.*?>)
```

and replaced with 
`$1newClass$2`

I had different attributes in each case, so I needed to take that into account.

Answer (score 1):

Look behinds can't be of variable length, so it's easier to just capture the whole line to the left of the target and put it all back with a back reference:

```
Search: ^(<div id="myDiv".*?class=")classToBeReplaced(?="[^<]*</div>)
Replace: $1newClass
```

Note that your flavour of regex may use back slashes instead of `$` for back references, ie you may need `\1newClass` instead.

Comment: What about the following pattern: `<div id="myDiv"><div class="classToBeReplaced"></div></div>`

Comment: @CommuSoft won't work of course, but OP doesn't seem to have that problem.

Comment: Nevertheless I think it is simply bad practice to use regex for xml/html processing. Tools like xslt are more suited for this task.

Comment: @CommuSoft what if OP is editing a large source file doing a once-off refactoring? A regex replace is the only way to go.

Comment: there are xml SAX parsers and processors that have the same time complexity and negligible memory complexity to do this.

Comment: @CommuSoft you can not use "xml SAX parsers and processors" within a text editor, so it doesn't matter how fast or versatile they are. Regex search/replace on the other hand is available in most text editors and all IDEs.

Comment: The OP says he has a lot of those files, given you have to process 1k+ files, one writes a bash script (or something equivalent).

Comment: @CommuSoft you can process all files with a single bash command that uses `sed` to do an in-place replacement. It's not a big deal.

Comment: About bash: this is to show that it is no big deal that you cannot do xml processing in a text editor. The first comment is not about regexes not being a nice tool. The comment is about the fact that xml/json/html/... other recursive languages, are no good candidates for regex processing, and therefore one better uses tools that result in less errors. I think it is possible that the `div` with `"myDiv"` does not have the correct class, but that the class is defined elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. classtobereplaced is defined elsewhere, but it is used correctly in some cases. I don't actually need to replace in divs with that id, this is just an example that would fit my case, and it was simpler to explain. I'm not sure if it was the best example, though. In my case, what I really need to to is to replace a class in some inputs that have a specific value.

Comment: What I actually ended up using, after your asnwer @Bohemian, was this:
 (myDiv.*?)classToBeReplaced(.*?>) 
and replaced with $1newClass$2
Because I had different attributes in each case, so I needed to take that into account. But your answer really helped! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well your question, you can do something like this:

```
class="classToBeReplaced"
```

With replacement string:

```
class="classYouWant"
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/zI0nY1/1)**

On the other hand, if you want to replace your div only, you could use:

```
(<div id="myDiv".*)"classToBeReplaced
```

With replacement string:

```
\1"classNEW"
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/zI0nY1/3)**

Comment: I think only for a given id?

Comment: @CommuSoft, yes thought the same, just updated it now. Thanks to point that